# Cordova Admob Pro - PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION Error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am setting up Cordova Admob Pro (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) on my project and I am getting error when building (https://build.phonegap.com)

ERROR:

`Could not get unknown property 'PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler`.

MY CODE:

```
function adSetter(){
alert(navigator.userAgent);
var admobid = {};
// select the right Ad Id according to platform
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1657046752'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
    };
}

if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
    isTesting:true, //Remove this Before publishing your app
    adId:admobid.banner, 
    position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
    autoShow:true} );

}
  function onDeviceReady(){
  alert("device ready");
      adSetter();
  }


window.load=function(){
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

CONFIG:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="^2.35.3">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.0" />
</plugin>
<engine name="android" spec="~7.1.4" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out the cause of the problem and a fix?  I didn't have this problem in version 2.26.0 but the latest release is throwing the error.

Comment: Hi! @cminus I put this on my config

   `<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />`
    `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />`